# Entity Framework: DefiningQuery error

Tags: .net, sql, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a Junction table with clustered index

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MeetingTags] (
    [MeetingId] INT NOT NULL,
    [TagId]     INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_MeetingTags_Tags] FOREIGN KEY ([MeetingId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Meetings] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Tags_MeetingTags] FOREIGN KEY ([TagId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tags] ([Id])
);

GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [cdxMeetingTags]
    ON [dbo].[MeetingTags]([MeetingId] ASC, [TagId] ASC);
```

Obviously, it has common field of the table Meetings and Tags so that I can add record on it by this way

```
var tag= new Tag()
{
  Title = "Meeting Title",
};

meeting.Tags.Add(tag);
```

Looks good, however I'm getting this error in `Context.SaveChanges()` when Inserting new Tags record.

```
Unable to update the EntitySet 'MeetingTags' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation
```

Tags has Primary Key.

I think putting a Primary Key in the `MeetingTags` is not possible as it will break the Many-to-Many relationship of Meeting and Tags in the EF, and it will also add `Meeting.MeetingTags.Tags` in the syntax instead of just `Meeting.Tags`

Any workaround on this?

Comment: Ive searched a bit and it seems like Composite Primary key is the solution. Anyone can point me how to create composite primary key in the MeetingTags table? is it supported by EF / SQL Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out creating Composite Primary Key and retaining the FK Constraint is possible and solve my problem.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MeetingTags] (
    [MeetingId] INT NOT NULL,
    [TagId]     INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_UserGroup PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([MeetingId], [TagId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_MeetingTags_Tags] FOREIGN KEY ([MeetingId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Meetings] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Tags_MeetingTags] FOREIGN KEY ([TagId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Tags] ([Id])
);
```